# How to fill pandas dataframe columns with random dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, random

I'm new to Pandas and I would like to play with random text data. I am trying to add 2 new columns to a DataFrame df which would be each filled by a key (newcol1) + value (newcol2) randomly selected from a dictionary.

```
countries = {'Africa':'Ghana','Europe':'France','Europe':'Greece','Asia':'Vietnam','Europe':'Lithuania'}
```

My df already has 2 columns and I'd like something like this :

```
    Year Approved Continent    Country
0   2016      Yes    Africa      Ghana
1   2016      Yes    Europe  Lithuania
2   2017       No    Europe     Greece
```

I can certainly use a for or while loop to fill df['Continent'] and df['Country'] but I sense .apply() and np.random.choice may provide a simpler more pandorable solution for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep, you're right. You can use `np.random.choice` with `map`:

```
df

    Year Approved
0   2016      Yes
1   2016      Yes
2   2017       No

df['Continent'] = np.random.choice(list(countries), len(df))
df['Country'] = df['Continent'].map(countries)

df

    Year Approved Continent    Country
0   2016      Yes    Africa      Ghana
1   2016      Yes      Asia    Vietnam
2   2017       No    Europe  Lithuania
```

You choose `len(df)` number of keys at random from the `country` key-list, and then use the `country` dictionary as a mapper to find the country equivalents of the previously picked keys.

Comment: Brilliant ! I thought I had to go in one go, I now understand the various 2-step mapping options.

Comment: @ozaarm keep in mind that with every version older than 3.6, you need a two step solution. To do it in a single step on python3.6, you can use random.choices as the other answer shows, but speed would still be a concern of mine then.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using [`DataFrame.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample):

```
df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(list(countries.items()), columns=["continent", "country"])
    .sample(len(df), replace=True)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Which can be made faster if your continent-country map is already a dataframe.

---

If you're on Python 3.6, another method would be to use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(choices([*countries.items()], k=len(df)), columns=["continent", "country"])
)
```

`random.choices()` is similar to [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy-random-choice) except that you can pass a list of key-value tuple pairs whereas `numpy.random.choice()` only accepts 1-D arrays.