# Python fill out multiple columns with random values from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill multiple columns of a dataframe with random values from a dictionary. From a [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464362/how-to-fill-pandas-dataframe-columns-with-random-dictionary-values) I understood that you could specify a list and have a column filled with random values from that list like this:

Dataframe:

```
   Col1  Col2 Col3
1  NaN   NaN  values
2  NaN   NaN  .
3  NaN   NaN  .
```

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df['Col1'] = np.random.choice(my_list, len(df))
```

The code would then fill the column like this:

```
   Col1  Col2 Col3
1  b     NaN  values
2  d     NaN  .
3  a     NaN  .
```

What I want is to fill out multiple columns and while the first thought would be to use something ugly like this:

```
my_list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_list2 = ['k', 'l', 'e', 'f']
df['Col1'] = np.random.choice(my_list1, len(df))
df['Col2'] = np.random.choice(my_list2, len(df))
```

I would like to declare a dictionary of lists and somehow call a function that maps the random values to their respective columns:

```
my_dict = {'Col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
           'Col2': ['k', 'l', 'e', 'f']}
df = <insert function to fill columns>
```

And then the dataframe would end up looking like this:

```
   Col1  Col2 Col3
1  b     l    values
2  d     f    .
3  c     k    .
```

Note that I would only want to fill out a certain amount of columns in my dataframe and not all of them

Comment: would `df = pd.Dataframe(my_dict)` do the job?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should've specified that these are not the only columns in the data frame and that I would like to fill out only a chosen amount of columns. I assume your suggestion would work if both data frames were the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you where you need to go:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    df[k] = np.random.choice(v, len(df))
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick, however I can't help but wonder if there's a fancier way of doing this (without a loop).

Comment: @DanG Filling out multiple columns will necessarily require some type of looping - unless you know ahead of time exactly how many or which columns you want filled in. There's nothing wrong with using loops in this case since we're not iterating through the dataframe but rather through the reference dictionary - it's plenty fast.

Answer (score 0):

@vtasca's answers is perfectly fine. Because you asked about other ways of doing this though, here's a fun way using dictionary comprehensions. It's a loop hiding behind some makeup:

```
chosen = {k: np.random.choice(v, len(df)) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(chosen)], axis=1)
```